# What are the differences between "to talk" and "to speak"?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Both verbs "to talk" and "to speak" refer to the same action.

Is their meaning exactly the same?
When is more appropriate to use one, or the other verb?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using **speak**, **tell**, **say**, and **talk** is a very common problem for ELL.

@Siddhartha and @Em1 gave great answers, so let me quickly list only those aspects not mentioned by them.

So, I have some meaning to convey. How do I know which word to use?

- **Ability** — if it's about ability, *"talk"* is preferred: "*cats can't **talk***", "*when I'm drunk I lose my ability to **talk***". Note that *"speak"* is allowed but is less popular;
- **Languages** — use *"speak"*: "*I **speak** English*";
- **Action** — covered in answers above; both words can be used; *"speak"* is mostly about single-direction, while *"talk"* usually refers a conversation (and is less formal);
- **Express information** — use *"say"* or *"tell"*: "*I **told** her that I love her*". Here, "I love her" is the information being expressed. *"Say*" can also be used, but it connotates a single-time action. Compare: "*I **said** that the discussion is over and hung up the phone.*"

Consider this sentence:

> *I can see they are **talking**, but I don't know what they are **saying***.

Here, you see an *action*, but you don't know or don't understand the meaning of the information others are exchanging.

- **Wide topic, narrow topic**:

  - use *"say"* or *"tell"* if the topic is narrow or it's about a small piece of information: *"I **told** her there is a party tonight"*;
  - use *"talk about"* or *"speak about"* when the topic is wide: *"We are **speaking** about history"*. There's also an idiomatic construct, *"talk politics"* that omits *"about*".
- Conversing during an **extended period of time**: use *"talk about"* or *"speak about"*, as above;
- **Imperative** usually follows the rules above, but due to an extended popularity, here's a brief:

  - *Extended time* or *dialogue* — *"**Talk** to me."*
  - *Long monologue* — *"**Tell** me about your problem."*
  - *Short monologue* — *"**Say** something!"*
  - Requesting a certain *attribute of speaking process* — *"**Speak** slowly please."*

Comment: Very good summary.

Comment: I will choose this answer because it is fairly comprehensive, but thanks to everyone.

Comment: Would a sentence like this be considered correct by native English speakers : "People wouldn't **speak** this sentence with a stress on the last word."? More generally: is the use of "speak" like used here common enough to be considered acceptable by native speakers?

Answer (score 14):

In hope not to *talk nonsense*, here's my summary:

Both words have a quite broad set of definitions with subtle differences. When referring to a conversation between people there isn't a significant difference and both words can be used interchangeably. You can *speak* and *talk* to someone about something.

> I talked to him yesterday.
>
> May I speak with you for a minute?

If a conversation, however, is rather a discussion, *talk* might be the better choice.

> We need to talk.

If a "conversation" is directed in one way only, e.g. giving a speech or speaking on the radio, than you should go with *speak*.

> He spoke at the conference.

When referring to the usage and knowledge of languages, *talking* means just to use words and *speaking* means to be able to use a particular language. Many sources states that *talk a language* is simply wrong but you will find definitions on that in several dictionaries though.

> I speak English and German.
>
> I can't understand him because he talks Mandarin.

*Speak* can express the ability to use your voice.

> I can't speak any more because of a throat injury.

And as Siddhartha mentions in the other answer, *speak* is more formal  than *talk*.

> Could I speak to the director, please?

Comment: Although even public speaking can be described with "talk"... "I attended a talk on..."  (although it still has a less formal connotation then).

Comment: Great example. We would never say 'I attended a speak'.

Comment: That's true but there is a shift here from verb to noun, and the original question focused on the verbal usage. Another variant in your example could be 'lecture' - which is definitely one-way!

Answer (score 2):

There is little difference between the two words.

> *Speak*
>   verb [no object]
>   say something in order to convey information, an opinion, or a feeling.

> *Talk*
>   verb [no object]
>   speak in order to give information or express ideas or feelings; converse or communicate by spoken words.

These two words can often be used interchangeably. *Speak* is more formal, but it also gives a sense of **one-sided communication**.
Therefore, when the President is giving a speech, we don't say:

> The President *talked* about XY issues. **[Example 1]**

We say:

> The President *spoke* about XY issues. **[Example 2]**

Although, if the President is ***discussing*** these issues, we may use *talked* (Example 1).

Comment: In the example about the President, "spoke" implies he was giving a speech; "talked" could also mean that, but could also mean that he was, for example, involved in a discussion about those issues.