# Why is "Mary told the cake to be cut by John" ungrammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> Mary told the cake to be cut by John.

A textbook says that this example is ungrammatical, but it seems to make sense to me: where does the sentence have its fault?

Comment: A good question! It might help to note that although "Mary told John to cut the cake" and "Mary told the cake to be cut by John" are non-equivalent (and the latter is semantically bizarre), there are some verbs that do allow this: "Mary expected John to cut the cake" and "Mary expected the cake to be cut by John" *are* roughly equivalent. (In technical terms, *tell* is a "[control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_%28linguistics%29) verb" whereas *expect* is a "[raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29) verb".)

Comment: What textbook said it's ungrammatical? (Apparently it didn't say why?)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is a grammatical sentence, but it would be very unusual for anyone to say it because Mary is telling the cake, an inanimate object, to do something (have John cut it). It would make more sense to say:

> Mary told John to cut the cake.

The main difference is to whom or what Mary is speaking. In the example in the question, she is speaking to the cake. In the example in this answer, she is speaking to John.

Comment: We must have different definitions of "grammatical". I don't think OP's sentence is remotely so, even allowing for thev fact that cakes can't take instructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think a command or request given in the passive voice is ungrammatical, but I do think it is bad style. Although the cake can't follow instructions, it is possible (albeit absurd) to talk to a cake.

Comment: Oh cake, thou cake! Prepare thyself, for John approaches with his mighty blade to cut thee. Allow thyself the blade to slice. And thou art cut, oh cake, in twain.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with you. It would be grammatical to say "Mary told the cake to **allow itself** to be cut by John", and Mary could tell the cake to cut John. But I'm not sure she could tell the cake TO BE cut.

Comment: @ctype.h: Granted, the fact that the cake itself can't logically be "told" anything doesn't mean OP's construction is ungrammatical. But as indicated in my own answer, the construction isn't valid according to "current" grammar even if you replace the cake with a person.

Comment: If the cake were told to "have John cut it" it would be grammatical; but it's not told to act, it's told to be acted upon, and that's not grammatical.

Comment: @snailplane  No; the words don't fit together. At least not with each other.

Comment: The cake asked, "Mary, by whom should I be cut?" and Mary told the cake to be cut by John.

Comment: @snailplane: I don't think that example has anything to do with it - it's *impossible* to envisage what those words "mean", whereas we know perfectly well what OP's sentence is "supposed" to mean. Jim's fanciful interpretation is only possible if we discard the infinitely more likely scenario that the speaker hasn't grasped the relevant grammar.

Comment: *Mary told her son to be educated by a proper teacher, rather than by his friend*. Is that correct, then?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but the fact remains that the *reason* we find Jim's interpretation so fanciful (and therefore un"likely") is semantics (meaning, or lack thereof), not grammar. Unless you're saying that an imperative followed by a passive is ungrammatical?

Comment: @LarsH: I don't like the word "ungrammatical" in this context, but yes - I am saying that I don't like the *imperative + passive* at all. By which I mean that, for example, *"Why don't you be taught to drive?"* doesn't pass muster for me. I want to hear an "active" verb, so it has to be *"Why don't you **learn** to drive?"* Maybe that's an extreme case, but I don't like constructions that even come *near* it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Since the OP asked why the sentence was ungrammatical, I think we should stick to that question; also because questions of taste (what someone likes) are solipsistic, if I'm using that word correctly. I think it would be hard to make the case that *imperative + passive* is grammatically nonstandard. Two occurrences of "be filled" (imper.) come to mind from the NASB and ESV: James 2:16, and Eph. 5:18 (http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%202:16&version=ESV) and that's without searching.

Comment: @LarsH: The fact that you can find the odd biblical usage with that general type of construction isn't really relevant. Do *you*, for example, like *"Why don't you be taught to drive?"*. If you do, I think you're in the minority. If you don't, *why not?* Note that I don't consider the word "grammatical" in the least useful here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think the biblical usages are "odd" (unrepresentative); the King James, which exerted great influence on the literary patterns of modern English, says "be ye warmed and filled" too. (I can't find an English corpus search service that tags imperatives.) Since you asked, I agree that your example sentence sounds awkward, though there are probably contexts in which it sounds more natural. However my interest is in the question of grammaticality, and yours doesn't seem to be there, so I will stop bothering you. :-)

Comment: Anyone can tell you that the exception part of your answer was not necessary, except perhaps as ample precaution. The sentence indeed is grammatical.

Comment: To flip "Mary told John to cut the cake" into the passive voice, you would say "John was told to cut the cake by Mary."

Answer (score 42):

"Mary told the cake to be cut by John" is, IMHO, not ungrammatical but simply nonsensical. We don't tell cakes to be cut by anyone; we tell people to cut cakes. That's a semantic restriction and a usage problem: it's not idiomatic English.

Consider this one:

> If you're gonna work for the Mob, you're gonna end up dead sooner than later. If yuh die young, it's prob'ly 'cause someone's gonna shoot yuh. The least you can do for your poor old mom is **to be murdered by someone who has oodles of money**. Then I can sue for wrongful death in civil court and win millions, just like the plaintiffs in the O. J. Simpson case did.

Same grammatical structure but different lexemes. Clear meaning. Grammatical. Semantically sound.

Rudolf Carnap created the sentence "Pirots carulize elatically", which contains no English words but, like Chomsky's "colorless green ideas" sentence, is perfectly grammatical and semantically nonsensical.

Is there a real and consistent connection between grammar and semantics? What is it? Is saying "I poured a yak into my cup and drank it" **ungrammatical** because it's not possible to pour a yak into a cup or to drink a yak? Or is this merely an example of nonsense (violation of semantic restrictions) in a real-world (vs. a fantasy-world or contrived) context?

When we deal with semantic restrictions on lexical items (words), are we concomitantly dealing with grammatical restrictions? I don't think so. If a sentence has a clear and discernible meaning but violates a syntactic rule, then there's a grammar problem; if it has no clear and discernible meaning but violates no syntactic rule, there's a semantic problem; if it has no clear and discernible meaning **and** it violates a syntactic rule, then there are semantic and grammar problems.

We can see that the syntax of "Man bites dog" and "Dog bites man" are exactly the same, NP-V-NP, but the semantics are different. Both sentences are meaningful and grammatical. Using the same syntactic structure but different lexemes, however, "Man drinks beer" and "Beer drinks man" is quite a different story. The first is both grammatically correct and semantically meaningful, but the second is grammatically correct and semantically nonsensical.

What have grammar and semantics to do with each other in this case? Nothing. The second sentence violates a semantic restriction: Beer is a liquid; it is drunk but cannot drink. Therefore, "Beer drinks man" is impossible in real-world English; it is **not ungrammatical**, however, because it violates no grammar rules, only semantic rules.

Usage isn't grammar and it's not necessarily semantics: it's a set of commonly expressed and commonly understood linguistic formulae (idioms, whether they're common and simple, like "Hello" or "The line's {busy / engaged}", or more complicated, like "He bought the farm" for "He died") in a particular linguistic community that ranges from very local (small social group) to international (virtually all native speakers of a language).

Comment: Great answer exhibiting differences among _syntactical_,_semantic_,_grammatical_ aspects of a construction. This is the point every other answerers missed till now. If I could, I up-voted it +1000! :)

Comment: A word, however, has both semantic and grammatical 'meaning'. A verb imposes syntactic constraints: *✲He said me to go* is ungrammatical, not unmeaningful, *✲She told the cake to cut itself* is unmeaningful, not ungrammatical, *✲She told the cake to be cut by John* is both unmeaningful and ungrammatical.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't understand "grammatical meaning". *S1 violates grammatical restrictions [wrong verb form: must be _said to_ (requiring _told_ is word choice: semantics)]; *S2 violates semantic restrictions [nonsense: cakes don't hear or understand & can't cut themselves]; & *S3 violates semantic restrictions but is perfectly grammatical. Semantics is about word meanings; grammar is about word forms, not word meanings; syntax is about word order; & acceptability is about usage norms (idiomaticity) & trumps semantics, grammar, & syntax. I said all this (more or less) in my answer.

Comment: 1)I was following the use which appears to have superseded that you and I grew up with: *grammar* embraces both *morphology* and *syntax*.  I will here follow the old use. 2)We agree that *He said me to go* violates the syntactical constraint that the person commanded by the verb *say* must be cast as an indirect object through a prepositional phrase headed by *to*. It also violates the syntactical constraint that the action commanded must be expressed as either a subordinated finite clause (e.g. *that he must go*) or a direct quote. ...

Comment: ...3)We agree that *She told the cake to cut itself* violates the semantic constraint that the person commanded by the verb *tell* must be capable of agency with respect to the action commanded.  4)We agree that *She told the cake to be cut by John* violates the same semantic constraint. I further maintain that it violates the syntactic constraint that the person commanded must be the agent of the action commanded; but in a passive construction the subject is not the agent but the patient of the action. If this were not the case, then there would be no semantic violation in this sentence.

Comment: Well, you distinguished them: "grammar is about word forms, not word meanings; syntax is about word order". But ADJ ADJ Npl Vipl ADV violates no grammatical constraints, only semantic constraints. Ten years before Chomsky my father was giving his students grammatical sentences composed of non-words like *gurzling* and challenging them to parse them purely on the basis of morphology and syntax; he *then* moved on to discussing both semantic and syntactical constraints imposed by specific words. *Grammatical* ≠ *acceptable*, as you say; but likewise *unacceptable*≠ *ungrammatical*.

Comment: @StoneyB: [REVISED COMMENT] Grammar does embrace morphology & syntax. The syntax error, however, is based on meaning, not on the grammatically required order of words in the S. It's a usage error, not a grammar error: not idiomatic.  If semantic nonsense like "Colorless green ideas..." is grammatical, then so is semantic nonsense like "She told the cake to be cut by John", regardless of semantic/usage-based syntax error, otherwise we have a double standard. This isn't like quantum physics or inorganic chemistry: there are no inviolable laws in linguistics.

Comment: And **acceptable ≠ grammatical**: "He gave it to you and **I**". If Chomsky was your father ["Ten years before **Chomsky my father** was giving his students..."], then you must have met my #1 son. :-)

Answer (score 21):

REVISED 11/03/2014
*Tell* in its ordinary sense takes three arguments: a Subject (S) who tells, an (optional) Indirect Object (IO) to whom the telling is addressed, and a Direct Object (DO) which is what is told:

> [<sub>S</sub> **Mary**] **told** [<sub>IO</sub> **John**] [<sub>DO</sub> **a story**].

This structure is maintained when *tell* is used in the sense *command* or *instruct*; the difference is that the DO is cast as an infinitive clause and signifies what action the IO is told to perform:

> [<sub>S</sub> **Mary**] **told** [<sub>IO</sub> **John**] [<sub>DO</sub> **to cut the cake**].

- (NOTE: Many grammarians would object to my calling this infinitive clause a DO; if you would rather call it an infinitival complement or something of that sort I won't mind. What you call it doesn't really affect the argument.)

But in this case *John* plays **two** roles: as **1)** Indirect Object of Mary's action and **2)** as the Subject of the infinitive clause. Moreover, the semantics of *tell* imposes two constraints on who may act in this dual role: it must be some entity which is capable of both **1a)** receiving the command and **2a)** performing it.

Your sentence violates both of these constraints: a cake is insensible, so it cannot receive a command, and inanimate, so it cannot perform a command.

Furthermore, your sentence casts the infinitive in the passive voice, and this will almost always violate constraint 2a; for the Subject of a passive construction is by definition not the **Agent** of the action, its performer, but its **Patient**, the entity upon which the action is performed. For example:

> Mary told John to be beheaded.

It is (almost) inconceivable that John could perform his own beheading, or that Mary could issue the command "John, behead yourself". If Mary wishes John to be beheaded she must issue the command to some third party capable of performing the execution.

And if you want to express this action in the passive—for instance, if you don't know who actually performed the execution—you have to use some other verb than *tell*:

> Mary ordered/commanded/decreed that the cake be cut by John.

A passive infinitive with *tell* is only acceptable in cases where the passive somehow retains a sense of Agency. Araucaria offers an interesting example:

> He told me to be guided by my conscience.

In this case there is a 'hidden' term in that passive: what my mentor really demands of me is that I *submit* to the guidance of my conscience or that I *choose* to be guided by my conscience rather than by my interest.

Comment: Help me out here! I need to deal with someone with a reasonable command of English! Putting aside the "inanimate cake" issue, I still maintain that *"Mary told Fred to be shaved by John"* is at the very least "highly questionable". But why, exactly?

Comment: Yes, this, exactly! If only I could +9000 ;).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I said, because with *tell* the person told must be the Agent of the action, not merely the subject of the verb. A passive is impossible. "*Mary told Fred to have himself shaved*" or "*to get himself shaved*" are OK.

Comment: @StoneyB Can you give a source for the rules you are invoking? I'm interested to read more into this.

Comment: @KenB  I'll have to hunt for one; my 'authority' right now is just me!

Comment: This rule regarding passive voice is beginning to feel to me a bit like the rule regarding ending sentences with prepositions, where *technically* you aren't supposed to, but strict adherence to the rule (or adherence at all) seems to be waning ever more as time (and the language) progresses.

Comment: @KenB  No, this is not a *general* rule, but one specific to *tell*. The *avoid the passive voice* is a different animal. No reputable stylist has ever advanced this as a **rule**; but many have advanced it as a *caution*, because in some quarters -- notably scientific writing, and writing which tries to look scientific -- it is overused, often grotesquely.

Comment: @StoneyB I know, I mean this rule in particular. I wouldn't think it's unique to *tell*; I would think it applies to any similar command verb requiring an actor. For example, consider *make*: would it be grammatical to say "Mary *made* the cake be cut by John"? How about "Mary *caused* the cake to be cut by John"? From where I'm sitting, if these phrases are grammatical, there is no reason for the above with *tell* to be considered ungrammatical.

Comment: @KenB  Each verb has its own rule. Normally *make* works like *tell*: *Mary made John cut the cake.* I don't like your example, but you might get away with it--BUT it's not a marked infinitive (folks disagree about what it it *is*, bare infinitive or mandative subjunctive). Your *cause* example is fine. *Have* is another pattern: *Mary had the cake cut by John*, *Mary had John cut the cake* are both OK. *Command* and *order*: *Mary commanded/ordered John to cut* or *that John cut* or *that the cake be cut* (again unmarked or subjunctive in the last).

Comment: +100 for the clear examples which I'm sure will help learners of English but -100 for the first sentence, which I am finding it hard to understand myself as I have never studied linguistics. I accept I may be ignorant on these matters but if ELL is to be useful for the vast majority then everyone ought to write in plain English so that even a layman can understand.

Comment: How about "He told me to be guided by my conscience" ?

Comment: Well, you could just reword it so it says something like "the Agent and an active.... or the Patient and a passive ... or something, I suppose? Or put in a hedgy *usually* or something.. :) I agree with your *submit to your conscience* analysis, maybe there's something with that...

Comment: @Araucaria, StoneyB: Let's not throw out the baby with the bathwater here! Concentrating on the semantics, there's a strong argument for saying that John is much more of an "agent" when he's *being guided by his conscience* than when he's *being seen by a dentist*.

Comment: @Araucaria, FumbleFingers Take a look.

Comment: An example of this construction (imperative + passive) from a nursery rhyme: _Mrs. Bond she went down to the pond in a rage, With plenty of onions, and plenty of sage.
She cried, **"Come, little wag-tails, come, and be killed.**
For you shall be stuffed, and my customers filled!_

Comment: John knows he's going to be executed, and there's nothing he can do to change that. But he does have the choice of opting for the firing squad or the guillotine, and he's asking Mary for her advice about which would be the best (quickest? least painful?) option. In that context it wouldn't be ridiculous to report her giving him advice as ***Mary told John to be beheaded** (rather than risk being shot by a firing squad who might not make a "clean kill").*

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, since *the cake* is inanimate, Mary can't tell it anything. Secondly, even if we change it to, say,

> 1: *Mary told John to be seen by a dentist.*

...it still wouldn't be acceptable to many native speakers. If we look at an inarguably valid form:

> 2: *Mary told Bill to be quiet.*

...we can derive...

> 2a: *What did Mary say to Bill? She said "Be quiet!"*.

...but when we try that with...

> 1a: *What did Mary say to John? She said "Be seen by a dentist!"*.

...which is most emphatically *not* grammatically valid in current English. A long time ago, Mary could have said *"Be gone!"*. But that construction hasn't been valid within my lifetime, except when used facetiously.

---

As other answers and comments indicate, all native speakers agree that if we accept OP's construction as grammatical, it must mean Mary told the cake what to do (which I dismissed as semantically absurd).

*But* there's obviously disagreement among native speakers as to the "grammaticality" of my alternative example #1. Some (including myself) aren't comfortable with *"X **told** Y **to be** acted upon by Z"* because we think *Y* can only be told *to **do** something* (even if it's a relatively "passive" action, such as ***allowing*** Z to perform the primary act). Others see no such constraint.

In this context it's important to remember that "grammar" isn't a pre-existing objectively-defined set of rules setting out what people can and can't say. That's just how it's usually presented to learners, but in reality it's a set of (more- or less-well observed) principles *derived* from what people *actually* say.

At the level of my example #1, therefore, it's meaningless to debate whether the form is objectively "grammatical" or not. To some native speakers, it's acceptable; to others, it's not.

Comment: +1 Yes; in modern use a passive of this sort is expressed with reflexive *get*: Mary told John to get himself seen by a dentist.

Comment: I agree generally, but why does it suddenly become valid when we introduce a negation? "Mary told John not to be seen by a dentist" is obviously correct for example.

Comment: @Matt Because it's a semantic constraint rather than a grammatical one.

Comment: @Matt: It's only "semantics" insofar as when you tell John *not to be seen*, you're effectively asking him to actively avoid being seen. And since the dentist isn't "actively" doing anything, in practice John is the agent of the act of not being seen. Anyway, I have to admit that even with that rationale, I still don't much like it. But what do I know? If I were Mary I'd tell John *not **to see** a dentist*. Your version sounds weird to me on all fronts.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but to this native speaker, "Mary told John to be seen by a dentist" is absolutely fine. It might be more common to say, "Mary told John to see a dentist", but I'd suggest that both are acceptable.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: It's a fine point, and in the end I don't think there can meaningfully be a "right" and "wrong" on this point. Some native speakers obviously have deep misgivings about the acceptability of ***telling** someone **to be** [passively acted upon by someone else]*. None of us feel it's acceptable to "tell" an inanimate cake to be thus acted upon. To some of us, that's because cakes can't take instructions in the first place; to others, it's because nothing and nobody can be thus instructed (they have to at least "actively" *submit* to being acted upon).

Comment: ...but in light of the various comments, I suppose I should at least change my *not acceptable to **most** native speakers* to *not **many***, since it's possible that's not the majority position.

Comment: @snailplane: In practical terms, grammaticality and acceptability are synonymous in contexts where all (or the vast majority) of native speakers agree. I'm just making the point because it's obvious some answerers/commenters are making appeals to a non-existent "objective" grammar to justify the fact that they find certain constructions acceptable which others don't. But this is an area where learners need to be careful they're not wasting time and effort trying to identify and commit to memory ill-defined principles that probably won't help much in other contexts.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but how about *Mary told John to be guided by his conscience* ?

Comment: @Araucaria: Excellent point! But notice how that transforms into the irreproachable *"**Be guided by your conscience**", said Mary to John*. I still think the active/passive distinction is central to this area, so I currently inclined to suppose it turns on the fact that being guided by your conscience is more "active" than being seen by a dentist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree!

Answer (score 8):

This sentence is grammatical. It is also nonsense. It means that Mary spoke to the cake, commanding it to have John cut it.

Comment: -1. I'm pretty sure it's NOT grammatical as well as nonsense. For example, saying "Mary told John to be cut by the murderer" is also wrong, and doesn't involve talking to cakes.

Comment: No, that is perfectly grammatical also, and also nonsense. Mary is now speaking to John telling him to be knifed by somebody.

Comment: "Mary told John to allow himself to be cut by the murderer" is grammatical. "Mary told John to cut the murderer" is grammatical. "Mary told John to get himself cut by the murderer" is grammatical. "Mary told John to be cut by the murderer" is NOT grammatical, because told requires an active verb. It cannot be used with "be/to be".

Comment: @Matt Have you never told anyone to be patient? ... to be still?

Comment: Yes. But I've never heard anyone be told to be stilled by someone else. The OP's sentence would be perfectly fine (if stilted and also nonsense) if it were "Mary told the cake to be cutting John."

Comment: @Matt "Mary told John not to be fooled by fad diets."

Comment: @Matt I don't think "grammar" means what you think it means.

Comment: @MετάEd Matt is right. The problem is not the infinitive form, but the passive voice. "Be still" and "be patient" are active voice. In the sentence "Mary told John to be still", John is the one performing the action of *being still*, which is fine. In the sentence "Mary told John to be stilled by George", George is the one performing the action, so Mary is telling John to... what? It's passive voice, and it's wrong.

Comment: What @KenB said. Casting it into the negative *(don't be fooled)* effectively creates an "active" voice. Grammatically speaking you *can't* tell someone ***to be** [acted upon] **by** someone else*, but you can tell them ***not to be...***

Comment: Not really. This is a difference between nonsense and incorrect grammar.

Answer (score 6):

@ctype.h's answer is correct: if the meaning is that Mary *instructed* John to cut the cake, then the phrase must be:

> Mary told John to cut the cake.

However, if the meaning is that Mary informed someone that cutting cake is John's obligation (and nobody else's), it should be:

> Mary **said**  **that** the cake **was** to be cut by John.

- *Said*, not *told*, because she's not actually requesting John to do it; Instead, she's informing someone about the "destiny" of the cake. See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/636/27) for details;
- *that* provides a link between the main phrase (*Mary said*) and the additional phrase;
- *was* is used here because it's impossible to use *to* without it;
- Note a special role of *to be*. It's a relict of an old form of *be* in the context of intention or obligation: [This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/2499/27) has more details.

Comment: Neither OP's original, nor your *Mary said that the cake to be cut by John*, are grammatically valid.

Comment: You're joking! I don't like to "pull rank", but as a native speaker familiar with a fair number of dialectal variations, I have to say I don't think *any* native speakers would find your sentence acceptable. Can you point me to a "dictionary" that seems to endorse it?

Comment: It would still sound very strange, but I think the sentence could be called grammatical if changed to "Mary said that the cake *was* to be cut by John." In the last link you gave, your example is also missing the "was"; it should read "I gave orders that Jane Eyre {*was* to} be left in the red-room." The "was" is very important.  Still, it's a very odd-sounding sentence.

Comment: @bytebuster, Oh! I get it. So the writer of the textbook want to say that ‘tell’ needs three arguments ‘who, to whom, what.’ So should have wanted to say ‘Mary told [the cake to be cut by John]’ has missed one argument for ‘to whom.’ But he missed also that ‘the cake’ can be a personified listener: On the contrary ‘say’ is a word needing two arguments (subject, object), there would be no argue on the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mary said that the cake to be cut by John is impossible. Cake *must be cut* or *should be cut* or, as @WendiKidd says, *was to be cut* are OK.

Comment: @WendiKidd: It's a little formal/stilted, but *"I gave orders that Jane Eyre be left in the red-room."* is 100% grammatically valid, with or without interpolated *"was to"*. But that "subjunctive" form isn't valid with something like **"I told him that the book be left in the room"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the answer I took the original sentence from, it said quote: "I gave orders that Jane Eyre {to} be left in the red-room." I was pointing out that the same mistake was made there as in this answer; you can't use "to" without the "was". :)  You're absolutely correct, of course--it was difficult for me to format the text within comments to show what I had added and what was taken from the source! I only added the "was"--everything else was in the original sentence in bytebuster's linked answer.

Comment: @bytebuster Modals always take the bare infinitive. If you mean ✲"Mary said that the cake be cut by John", that would be a *mandative subjunctive*--but say isn't mandative, so that's unacceptable too. "Mary ordered that the cake be cut by John" is an acceptable mandative.

Comment: @WendiKidd: oic. So actually, bytebuster is citing *his own invalid answer to a different question* as supporting evidence for doing it again here! (This thread will look really confusing to anyone else who wants to follow the matter up, since I've now corrected that original error! :)

Comment: @StoneyB Great, thanks a lot! I will change it to _was to be cut_ as it is closer to my original thought.

Comment: @snailplane: Agreed, and I've cancelled my downvote accordingly.